# Pyspark Error+Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working spark version 2.2.0,& Python 2.7.I'm connecting BigSQL using pyspark & trying to retrieve the data. Following are the code I used

```
import cPickle as cpick
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession 
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() 
spark_train_df = spark.read.jdbc("jdbc:db2://BigSQL URL:Port:sslConnection=true;","Schema.Table",
             properties={"user": "my userid", 
                      "password": "password",
                      'driver' : 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'})
spark_train_df.registerTempTable('data_table')
# query to get columns necessary to create indexes
sql = "select * FROM data_table"
train_df = spark.sql(sql)

cmr_dict = { 'date': time.strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y'),
            'description': '`cmrs` contains data from data_table',
           'cmrs': train_df}

with open('cmrs.pkl', mode='wb') as fp:
    cpick.dump(cmr_dict, fp, cpick.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

After running the code I'm getting error message

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o79.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to pickle Spark distributed objects. These are only proxies for JVM structures, not to mention they don't contain any data (only description of computation).

If you wan to pickle data, `collect` and serialize the result